# Are the Privilege levels in Meta the same as SFF?

Tags: support, privileges

I haven't spent much time on the Meta side of things so I'm a little confused on how it works. Obviously it's the same in the sense that users have access to both and all my rep carries over, but what about privileges? I don't see them listed on my user profile on the meta side. Is it just the same as SFF? Or are they separate for each, like the badges?

Sorry if this is said somewhere in the Help pages. I tried looking around but didn't see anything for it. If it exists a link to the page would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only privilege that's different is that it takes 5 rep to create posts on this meta site (with one [exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/323179)). Other than that, your main site rep is synced to meta hourly so you have the same reputation-based privileges you have on the main site. But no bounties, since you have no way to gain or lose reputation on meta sites like this.

Meta Stack Exchange, the meta for the entire network, does have differences, however (listed here: [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/323179)). It works more like a main site.